# js find object in nodeList?

Tags: javascript, object, nodes

Fallback is irrelevant. No libraries, please.

We have an dom object reference, we'll call `obj`. It's actually an event.target.

We have a node list, we'll call `nodes`, which we've gotten with querySelectorAll and a variable selector.

`nodes` may have 1 or many elements, and each each of those elements may have children.

We need to determine if `obj` is one of those node elements, or children elements of those node elements. We're looking for "native" browser functionality here, we can totes write our own `for` loop and accomplish this, we are looking for alternatives.

Something like:

`nodes.contains(obj)` OR `nodes.indexof(obj)`

Solutions involving other methods of retrieving the node list to match against are acceptable, but I have no idea what those could be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in DOM method for that. You'd need to recursively traverse your `NodeList`, and check for equality with your element. Another option is to use [`Element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll) on each first-level elements from your `NodeList` (looking for your element's id, for example). I'm not sure how (inn)efficient that would be, though.

Comment: Yeah this is our current school of thought as well. Well, sort of... the obj is from an event.target, so we would recurs through the parents, and match against our variable selector using matchesSelector. We have been unable to find a built-in method as well, but wanted to pick some great minds to see if we've missed.

Answer (score 22):

If <=IE11 is not a concern then I think the cleanest is to use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
Array.from(nodes).find(node => node.isEqualNode(nodeToFind));
```

Comment: You can use Node.isEqualNode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure if this will search beyond the first level of the NodeList, but you can use this expression recursively to traverse it and check if the element 'obj' is in the NodeList 'nodes'.

```
[].indexOf.call(nodes, obj)
```

Answer (score 7):

I did something like this:

```
Array.prototype.find.call(style.childNodes, function(child) {
  if(child.textContent.includes(drawer.id)) {
    console.log(child);
  }
});
```

Seems to work. Then child is another html node, which you can manipulate however you like.

Answer (score 3):

```
[...nodes].includes(targetNode)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements all other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dominic's answer as function:

```
function nodelist_contains (nodelist, obj)
{
  if (-1 < Array.from (nodelist).indexOf (obj))
    return true;
  
  return false;
}
```