# one eventlisterner for all elelemnts with same parent even thou some are placed in a variable which represents more than one node

Tags: javascript

Okay I want to organize my script and use 1 eventlistener for all of the events since all elements of those events belong to one parent, which is nav tag of the page, but I collected some of those elements through querySelectorAll meaning they are now Array, collection of objects, I want the logic of it be in this manner:

```
const topNav = document.querySelector(".topNav");
const topNavChildrenLis = document.querySelectorALL(".topNav li");

topNav.addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
if(event.target == topNavChildrenLis){

//do this and that
} 
//and so on and so forth for other elements 


});
```

I know this expression "event.target == topNavChildrenLis" does not work, I also tried to return nodes of the array by doing something like this "event.target == topNavChildrenLis.forEach((nodes)=>{
return nodes;
})" and it didn't work also, is there any way to do this?
Thanks for you help :)

Comment: `querySelectorAll` has no capital `ALL`, its `All`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, make the result of `const topNavChildrenLis = document.querySelectorALL(".topNav li");` and array, so you can use array methods

```
const topNavChildrenLis = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".topNav li"));
```

or

```
const topNavChildrenLis = [ ...document.querySelectorAll(".topNav li") ];
```

now you can do things like

```
let tgt = topNavChildrenLis.find(el => el === event.target);
```

now `tgt` will be event.target only if it exists in the array

Comment: So its not an array :-? Dude, I don't understand this line >>"let tgt = topNavChildrenLis.find(el => el === event.target);"  whats el here :-?

Comment: el is each element in the `topNavChildrenLis` array

Comment: and no, it's not an array, it's a HTMLCollection ... easily converted to an Array for all Array method goodness

Comment: why do I have to write it this way without bracket, even clearly you didnt use bracket becase you had one line of code, but when I add brackets it does not work..something here becomes bracket scoped and causes the code not to work, why is that, I just want to understand it compelety.
topnav.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
    if(topNavChildrenArray.find((node)=>node === event.target)){
alert("Mish");
    }  <<< this works
if(topNavChildrenArray.find((node)=>{node === event.target;})){
alert("Mish");
    } <<<< Thos does not.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` has no capital `ALL`, its `All`. Also, really no need to do `Array.from` as nowdays (but IE, which doesn't support `Array.from` either) a `NodeList` is iterable.

Comment: @LGSon - yeah, copied the question with the ALL ... but NodeList doesn't have `.find` ... so you either use `[...document.querySelectorAll]` or `Array.from`

Comment: This one might be another option, with better browser support: `[].indexOf.call(nodes, obj)`

Comment: ...and found that one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980527/js-find-object-in-nodelist and might be a duplicate